# Is any power of four equal to the sum of two different squares?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

More simply, is there a solution for:

$x^2+y^2=4^n$

where x, y, and n are positive integers and $x\neq y$.

My gut feeling says no, but I can't justify it with an actual proof.

If the answer is no, is there a simple proof as to why?

Comment: You can assume WLOG that at least one of $x$ and $y$ is odd (if not, divide both sides by $4$). Now take both sides $\bmod 4$.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. If the equation holds, then wouldn't both sides mod 4 always give 0?

Comment: @Dan:  you missed the point of dividing $x,y$ by $2$ if they are both even and reducing $n$ by $1$.  Eventually you have to get to a point where at least one is odd.

Comment: What is wrong with both x and y being odd? Can't the equation still hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $x,y$ are solutions to the equation $x^2+y^2=4^n$. Then we can write $x=2^ka,y=2^\ell b$ with $a,b$ odd, so we get $4^ka^2+4^\ell b^2=4^n$. WLOG $k\leq \ell$ so we have $a^2+4^{\ell-k}b^2=4^{n-k}$. If $k\neq\ell$, then we immediately have a contradiction because the left-hand side is odd and the right-hand side is even. Thus $k=\ell$. Therefore we have that $a^2+b^2=4^{n-k}=4^{n-\ell}$ where $a,b$ are odd. The square of any odd number is $1\pmod{4}$, so the left-hand side is $2\pmod{4}$. But the right-hand side is never $2\pmod{4}$ so there are no solutions.

**Note:** This doesn't use the assumption in the OP that $x\neq y$

Comment: I think I understand most of this. Can you just explain how you can assume that x and y can always be expressed as a power of two times an odd number?

Comment: @Dan It follows from Unique Prime Factorization, since $2$ is the only even prime and the product of odd numbers is odd. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Comment: Ok thank you, I think this makes perfect sense now. Although, should this sentence say left-hand side instead?

"The square of any odd number is 1(mod4), so the right-hand side is 2(mod4)."

Comment: @Dan yup! Fixed

Answer (score 1):

NO. (1). If $x,y$ are both odd then $x^2+y^2$ is congruent to $2$ modulo $4.$

(2). If there were a least $n$ such that $x^2+y^2=4^n$ with  $x\ne y$, then, as $x,y$ must both be even, let $x=2x'$ and $y=2y'$.

Then $0\ne x'\ne y'\ne y$ so $1<x'+y'\leq x'^2+y'^2=4^{n-1},$ so $n-1\geq 1.$ So $4^{n-1}$ is also a sum of two non-zero unequal squares, contrary to the minimality of $n.$

Another way of saying this is that if S is the set of all $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $4^n$ is the sum of $2$ unequal non-zero squares, then $n\in S\implies (n-1)\in S.$ A set $S\subset \mathbb N$ with the property that $n\in S\implies (n-1)\in S$ must be the empty set. (Else it would be a non-empty set of natural numbers with no least member.)